# Write data into Google Firestore in pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, apache-beam

I want to read data from Cloud BigQuery to Cloud Datastore through Dataflow runner with Apache Beam. From the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/), Firestore is not yet be supported. I write my own class to do it.

```
class UpdateIntoFireStore(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, element):
        try:
            cred = credentials.Certificate({
              "..."
            })

            firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
            'projectId': '...',
            })
        except ValueError:
            pass
        db = firestore.client()
        doc_ref = db.collection(u'poi')
        doc_ref.add(element)
```

The pipeline is as below:

```
job = ( p  | 'Read from BigQuery' >> Read(BigQuerySource(query="SELECT * FROM ...", use_standard_sql=True))
           | 'Update to Firestore' >> beam.ParDo(UpdateIntoFireStore()))
```

Is this approach fine? I am concerned about the influence of the parallel processing on these write operation on Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `start_bundle` to define your client.

> `start_bundle` - Called before a bundle of elements is processed on a worker.
>       Elements to be processed are split into bundles and distributed
>       to workers. Before a worker calls process() on the first element
>       of its bundle, it calls this method.

Much better approach:

```
class FirestoreDoFn(beam.DoFn):

def __init__(self):
    super(FirestoreDoFn, self).__init__()

def start_bundle(self):
    self.firestore_client = GoogleServices(
        crendential_path="<cred-path-in-here>"
    ).init_firestore(
        project_id="<your-project-id>",
        collection_id="<collection-id>"
    )

def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
    logging.info(element)
    # response = self.firestore_client.save()
    # logging.info("response: {}".format(response))
    return {"status":"ok"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly like making external calls from dataflow. Technically this will work. However there are a couple of things to be aware of.

1. There are no guarantees on how many times a single element will be processed so you might get multiple entries for the same element in firestore.
2. You will be making separate call for each element to the firestore and there is no caching of the firestore clients/connections.

Comment: Any suggestion to improve the existing code before waiting the FirestoreIO to be supported? Thanks